# como convertir código JS a Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Quería saber si pueden darme una ayuda para convertir el siguiente código de JS a TS para realizar una practica que estoy haciendo en angular.

```js
function eurosDolares(valNum) {
  document.getElementById("inputDolares").value = valNum * 0, 01;
}

function dolaresDolares(valNum) {
  document.getElementById("inputPesos").value = valNum * 151.80;
}
```

```html
<h2>Conversor de moneda.</h2>
<p>
  <label>Pesos</label>
  <input id="inputPesos" type="number" placeholder="Pesos" oninput="eurosDolares(this.value)" onchange="eurosDolares(this.value)">
</p>
<p>
  <label>Dolares</label>
  <input id="inputDolares" type="number" placeholder="Dolares" oninput="dolaresDolares(this.value)" onchange="dolaresDolares(this.value)">
</p>
```

Por otro lado estoy queriendo realizar el siguiente ejemplo que adjunto en imagen con un boton que hace que se inviertan los montos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy compleja: si quieres aprender Angular, busca algún tutorial, pero no intentes escribir una aplicación usando puro JS y luego pasarlo a la forma de trabajar de Angular. Typescript es un superconjunto de JS, por lo que todo JS válido es TS válido

Answer (score 2):

Los cambios son minimos recuerda que tu codigo en `ts` va a ser compilado a `js` por lo mismo lo que vas a agregar en este caso son unicamente los tipos tanto en funciones como en tus variables.

```js
function eurosDolares(valNum: number): void {
  document.getElementById("inputDolares").value = valNum * 0, 01;
}

function dolaresDolares(valNum: number): void {
  document.getElementById("inputPesos").value = valNum * 151.80;
}
```

por lo mismo la forma en la manejas los imputs puede ser expresa en la siguiente forma:

```js
let inputPesos: object = document.getElementById("inputPesos");
inputPesos.value = valNum * 151.80;
```

Sin embargo lo que te recomiendo es que revises la guia de [migracion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) de `js` a `ts`.

> Nota: Perdon por las tildes pero tengo mi ambiente en ingles.

Comment: Gracias por la info.